# Undefined variable in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, oop, crud

I'm making an web app with MySQL and PHP (OOP) thats has CRUD with multiple tables, and I'm trying to echo the variable but it returns this error:
*Warning: Undefined variable $id_customer*

Can someone help on what am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
if (isset($_GET["id_customer"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id_customer"]))) {
    require_once "../connectDB.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers 
            INNER JOIN Orders
            ON Customers.id_customer = Orders.id_customer
            WHERE Customers.id_customer = ?";

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $param_id);

        // Set parameters
        $param_id = trim($_GET["id_customer"]);

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $result = $stmt->get_result();

            if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
                /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set
                contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                // Retrieve individual field value
                $id_customer = $row["id_customer"];
                $fn_customer = $row["fn_customer"];
                $ln_customer = $row["ln_customer"];
                $email_customer = $row["email_customer"];
                $id_order = $row["id_order"];
                $order_dt = $row["order_dt"];
                $order_total = $row["order_total"];
                /* ?>
                // <p><?php echo $id_customer; ?></p>
                / <?php */
            }
        }
    }
    // Close statement
    $stmt->close();
        
    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();

}


?>

<p><?php echo $id_customer; ?></p>
```

I tried putting the echo together with the retrieve of the fields values, and out of the first statement, as it is now. None of this worked.

Comment: If the code block where the variable is defined is not executed the variable will be undefined, either define the variable in the top of the scope and initialize to `null` or just echo the varible inside the `if ($result->num_rows == 1)` , read more about [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Simple, the last time you echo $id_customer is outside the block where you define that variable. So in cases where the `$id_customer = ...` line isn't executed, the variable will be undefined. You'll need to debug your code to discover the precise circumstances- check which of the layers of `if` blocks that line is in, to see which block the code doesn't enter, and what values of the variables in the conditions caused that to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `isset($_GET['id_customer'])` is true AND a statement is successfully prepared AND successfully executed, then you run a query and initialize `$id_customer`. Yet, if you have no such parameter, it will not be initialized and you will get an error. Try initializing it no matter what before the `if`:

```
id_customer = '';
if (isset($_GET["id_customer"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id_customer"]))) {
    require_once "../connectDB.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers 
            INNER JOIN Orders
            ON Customers.id_customer = Orders.id_customer
            WHERE Customers.id_customer = ?";

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $param_id);

        // Set parameters
        $param_id = trim($_GET["id_customer"]);

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $result = $stmt->get_result();

            if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
                /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set
                contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                // Retrieve individual field value
                $id_customer = $row["id_customer"];
                $fn_customer = $row["fn_customer"];
                $ln_customer = $row["ln_customer"];
                $email_customer = $row["email_customer"];
                $id_order = $row["id_order"];
                $order_dt = $row["order_dt"];
                $order_total = $row["order_total"];
                /* ?>
                // <p><?php echo $id_customer; ?></p>
                / <?php */
            }
        }
    }
    // Close statement
    $stmt->close();
        
    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();

}


?>

<p><?php echo $id_customer; ?></p>
```

Comment: I already tried defining the variable outside the first ìf` statement (i forgot to mention that), but when I do this, there are no errors, but the webpage is blank (meaning that it's getting the first value, wich is blank. I think?)

Comment: @GabrielAraújo the problem is that the value was never properly defined. You need to end your URL with `?id_customer=123` in order to properly receive a customer. Since you have no such parameter, we are handling the case when it's not defined. The fact that you receive a blank page in this case is already signifying success. Now, you will need to pass a parameter properly and test it that way as well.

Comment: what is the best way I can pass the id?

Comment: @GabrielAraújo let's suppose your URL is of `http://some/path/somewhere`. You add a question mark to it and the parametername=parametervalue, like `http://some/path/somewhere?id_customer=123`. The 123 is just an example, replace it with your actual value.

Comment: It worked, but I can't this do manually, how can I do this in the code? Is something wrong in the `$param_id`?

Comment: @GabrielAraújo yes, specifically you are doing the `bind_param` before `$param_id` is being initialized. Invert the order of those two lines.

Comment: I already did as other user helped me, but it still doesn't work, it doesn't change the url to the actual id that I requested.

Comment: @GabrielAraújo your URL requests your PHP code, not the other way around. `$param_id` will not define a URL for you. It will store a value received from the database instead.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding, but how can I request the ID? I really don't know

Comment: @GabrielAraújo first the user visits your page, by typing/pasting a URL into the browser address bar or clicking a link or something of the like. Then, that URL is being sent to your server (which could be a computer at a remote place) via the internet. That computer receives the request parameters (`id_customer` in this case), which had to be in the request in the first place. Your server parses the request on a certain port (ex. port 80) and handles the request (triggers your PHP code to run) and when that's completed the response is sent back by the server to the browser.

Comment: @GabrielAraújo so, at the point when your server's PHP code runs, your request parameter, `id_customer` must already be present in the URL.

Comment: I don't understand how I can do that, I researched but nothing comes on how to do it.

Comment: @GabrielAraújo what are you confused about? Can you convert it into a simple question?

Comment: I understand what you are explaining, I don't know how to convert that into the code that I need

Comment: @GabrielAraújo in order to be able to help you on that I need to understand this more deeply. How would your app work exactly? Can you explain how a user should use it, what is the goal of the app, etc.?

Comment: It's a CRUD app, working on 3 tables: Customers, Orders and OrdersItems. This is the Read Customers file, here I want to join Customers and Orders of the selected Customer that the User using the app chose.

Comment: @GabrielAraújo how do you visit your application as a user?

Comment: this is like a Admin page, i'm doing this to study CRUD for a School Project. I'm using xampp, so I can access it by localhost.

Comment: @GabrielAraújo You have turned on your computer. You have started your browser. What do you type into your address bar?

Comment: i type localhost/(project folder), then I click on a link that my page has in homepage that goes to localhost/(project folder)/Customers.php, there it has all customer records, and a symbol to view each user record, that this problem happened

Comment: @GabrielAraújo okay/let's suppose your (project folder) is `foobar`. You visited localhost/foobar. What do you see there **exactly**?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues in your code, firstly you appear to be binding (`bind_param`) a variable (`$param_id`) which isn't yet defined which should error, but ultimately will return zero rows from your SQL query.

Secondly, where it is in the provided code, the `$id_customer` variable will only be defined in certain circumstances. There are 4 `if` statements which need to be true before `$id_customer` is declared. Should any of those 4 statements be false, it won't be assigned a value. So when you try to `echo` it at the end of your script, it won't be defined. Hence the error message.

It's difficult to provide you with an answer without understanding exactly what your script wants to achieve. But in short, `$id_customer` will only have a value inside the `if` statement `if ($result->num_rows == 1) { /** ... **/ }`.

The following will provide you with the desired output:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["id_customer"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id_customer"]))) {
    require_once "../connectDB.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers 
            INNER JOIN Orders
            ON Customers.id_customer = Orders.id_customer
            WHERE Customers.id_customer = ?";

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {

        // Set parameters
        // Define $param_id before use, otherwise you'll be binding an undefined or null variable = no results + error
        $param_id = trim($_GET["id_customer"]);

        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $param_id);

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $result = $stmt->get_result();

            if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
                /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set
                contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                // Retrieve individual field value
                $id_customer = $row["id_customer"];
                $fn_customer = $row["fn_customer"];
                $ln_customer = $row["ln_customer"];
                $email_customer = $row["email_customer"];
                $id_order = $row["id_order"];
                $order_dt = $row["order_dt"];
                $order_total = $row["order_total"];
                // $id_customer will be defined here
                ?>
                   <p><?php echo $id_customer; ?></p>
                <?php
            }
            // $id_customer MAY NOT be defined here
        }
        // $id_customer MAY NOT be defined here
    }
    // Close statement
    $stmt->close();
        
    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
    
    // $id_customer MAY NOT be defined here
}

// $id_customer MAY NOT be defined here

?>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I did put first the `$param_id`, and I changed the echo inside of `if ($result->num_rows == 1) {` statement, but it still doesn't work. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, since this 2 tables have data inside.

Comment: In which case the SQL is probably not returning any result. `var_dump` the contents of $row (`var_dump($row);`) after you `fetch_array`. This will firstly show you whether `$result->num_rows` is equal to 1 AND what the resulting SQL is.